# Avoid "SELECT TOP 1" and "ORDER BY" in Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have the very table in sql server 2008 with lot of data

```
|ID|Name|Column_1|Column_2|
|..|....|........|........|
```

more than 18,000 records. So i need to the the row with the lowest value of `Column_1` that is date but could by any data type (that is unsorted) so I use these sentence

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, Name from table ORDER BY Column_1 ASC
```

But this is very very slow. And i think that i don't need to to sort the whole table. My question es how to get the same date with out using `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`

Comment: What datatype is Column_1? Do you have an index on Column_1?

Comment: I presume from this that you do not have an index on `Column_1`?  If you're going to use it regularly, then that is what I would look at doing first

Comment: did you try `MIN()` on your column? Depending on datatype this might work

Comment: I edit for more info. Thank you

Comment: @norlando: Why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot see why 18,000 rows of information would cause too much of a slow down, but that is obviously without seeing what the data is you are storing.

If you are regularly going to be using the `Column_1` field, then I would suggest you place a non-clustered index on it... that will speed up your query.

You can do it by "designing" your table via Sql Server Management Studio, or directly via TSQL...

```
CREATE INDEX IX_myTable_Column_1 ON myTable (Column_1 ASC)
```

More information on [MSDN about creating indexes here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

---

**Update** thanks to comments by @GarethD who helped me with this, as I wasn't actually aware of it.

As an extra part of the above TSQL statement, it will increase the speed of your queries if you include the names of the other columns that will be used within the index....

```
CREATE INDEX IX_myTable_Column_1 ON myTable (Column_1 ASC) INCLUDE (ID, Name)
```

As GarethD points out, [using this SQLFiddle as proof](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a412b/1), the execution plan is much quicker as it avoids a "RID" (or Row Identifier) lookup.

More information on [MSDN about creating indexes with include columns here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx)

Thank you @GarethD

Comment: I agree with the premise, but you answer suggests a clustered index, yet your SQL would create a nonclustered index (which is what I assume would work as I'd imagine the column `ID` is a PK with a clustered index). So this should probably be cleared up, and I wasn't sure exactly what was meant so didn't want to vandalise your work. It may also be worth including `Name` in the index as a nonkey column (based on the query in the question)

Comment: Ack, you're right about the non-clusted @GarethD... typing too fast for my own good. I have edited accordingly.  Not sure about the need for including `Name` though

Comment: SOrry should have said ID and name, I thought there was no need to include a primary key in the nonkey columns. If you check the execution plans in [This Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a412b/1) you'll see that the second query (with nonkey columns included in the index) avoids a rid lookup so will inevitably perform better (for selects anyway).

Comment: @GarethD, hmmm, interesting - however, on first look at the fiddle, it showed 3ms for the first table and 37ms for the second, completely the opposite of what you said, but I think that was just a blip as it was faster on subsequent runs ;-) I will update my answer based on this observation many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Would this work faster?  When I read this question, this was the code that came to mind:

```
Select top 1 ID, Name 
from table 
where Column_1 = (Select min(Column_1) from table)
```

Comment: This would return multiple rows in the event that two `Column_1` has the same value, being the minimum.... and, even so, I wouldn't expect it to run faster.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that `Select min(Column_1) from table` will return 1 row even in the event of multiple minimums.  And even if it didn't, the `top 1` clause would still guarantee that only 1 row gets returned.  But yeah, I don't know if it would run faster or not.